# OpenGL Не получается нарисовать прямоугольники в нужном месте

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Привет! Я делаю игру. Entity не рисуются так, как задумано.

Как должно быть : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как **получилось** :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, проблема где-то в glTranslatef. Что думаете?

```
void MasterRenderer::renderScene() {
    prepareRenderer();
    glTranslatef(-tanks.at(0).getX() + 650.0f, -tanks.at(0).getY() + 300.0f, 0.0f);
//screen - 1300 x 600
    renderEntities();
    renderTanks();
    renderBullets();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glTranslatef(tanks.at(0).getX() - 650.0f, tanks.at(0).getY() - 300.0f, 0.0f);
}

void MasterRenderer::renderEntities() {
    std::pair<std::multimap<int, Entity>::iterator, std::multimap<int, Entity>::iterator> range;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        range = entities.equal_range(i);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures.at(i).getTexture());

        for (std::multimap<int, Entity>::iterator it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it) {

            glTranslatef((*it).second.getX(), (*it).second.getY(), 0.0f);
            glRotatef((*it).second.getAngle(), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f((float)(*it).second.getWidth() / -2.0f, (float)(*it).second.getLength() / -2.0f);
                glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f((float)(*it).second.getWidth() / 2.0f, (float)(*it).second.getLength() / -2.0f);
                glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f((float)(*it).second.getWidth() / 2.0f, (float)(*it).second.getLength() / 2.0f);
                glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f((float)(*it).second.getWidth() / -2.0f, (float)(*it).second.getLength() / 2.0f);
            glEnd();
            glRotatef(-(*it).second.getAngle(), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            glTranslatef(-(*it).second.getX(), -(*it).second.getY(), 0.0f);
        }

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }
}

void MasterRenderer::renderTanks() {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures.at(0).getTexture());
    for(Tank tank : tanks) {
        // танк
        glTranslatef(tank.getX(), tank.getY(), 0.0f);
        glRotatef(-tank.getAngle(), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(tank.getWidth() / -2.0, tank.getLength() / -2.0);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(tank.getWidth() / 2.0, tank.getLength() / -2.0);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(tank.getWidth() / 2.0, tank.getLength() / 2.0);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(tank.getWidth() / -2.0, tank.getLength() / 2.0);
        glEnd();
        glRotatef(tank.getAngle(), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glTranslatef(-tank.getX(), -tank.getY(), 0.0f);
    }
    // Башня
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures.at(1).getTexture());
    for(Tank tank : tanks) {
        glTranslatef(tank.getX(), tank.getY(), 0.0f);
        glRotatef(-tank.getTurretAngle(), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(tank.getTurretWidth() / -2.0f, tank.getTurretLength() / -2.0f + tank.getTurretOffset());
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(tank.getTurretWidth() / 2.0f, tank.getTurretLength() / -2.0f + tank.getTurretOffset());
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(tank.getTurretWidth() / 2.0f, tank.getTurretLength() / 2.0f + tank.getTurretOffset());
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(tank.getTurretWidth() / -2.0f, tank.getTurretLength() / 2.0f + tank.getTurretOffset());
        glEnd();
        glRotatef(tank.getTurretAngle(), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glTranslatef(-tank.getX(), -tank.getY(), 0.0f);
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

void MasterRenderer::renderBullets() {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures.at(2).getTexture());
    for(int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
        glTranslatef(bullets.at(i).getX(), bullets.at(i).getY(), 0);
        glRotatef(-bullets.at(i).getAngle(), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(bullets.at(i).width / -2.0f, bullets.at(i).length / -2.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex2f(bullets.at(i).width / 2.0f, bullets.at(i).length / -2.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(bullets.at(i).width / 2.0f, bullets.at(i).length / 2.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex2f(bullets.at(i).width / -2.0f, bullets.at(i).length / 2.0f);
        glEnd();
        glRotatef(bullets.at(i).getAngle(), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glTranslatef(-bullets.at(i).getX(), -bullets.at(i).getY(), 0);

        bullets.at(i).move();
        bullets.at(i).setLife(bullets.at(i).getLife() + 0.01f);
        if(bullets.at(i).getLife() >= 2.0f) bullets.erase(bullets.begin() + i);
        std::vector<Bullet>(bullets).swap(bullets);
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

void MasterRenderer::prepareRenderer() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0f, 1300.0f, 600.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
```

Помогите мне, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести значения X, Y, Angle для каждого Entity и их размеры. Также вы можете использовать glPush/glPopMatrix, чтобы не вызывать glRotatef и glTranslatef с обратными трансформациями.

Comment: 323.0 100.0 Угол : 0  Размеры :  297 60 / 
201.0 160.0 Угол : 0 Размеры : 122 276 / 
352.0 328.0 Угол : -37 Размеры :  288 196

Comment: Судя по всему эти координаты не точные. Попробуйте упросить себе задачу и вывести один прямоугольник правильно. Тогда вы может быть поймёте в чём дело. Как мне кажется вам необходимо разобраться, где у ваших прямоугольников находится точка (0, 0). Судя по всему это это верхний угол и исходя их этого задать положение.Попробуйте выложить скиншоты всего экрана,  а не только. Очень трудно по ним ориентироваться, тем более у вас там есть смещение танка. Его хорошо бы убрать для отладки проблемы.